# Validate multiple HTML pages in single click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

I have a SPA which contains in 4 HTML pages(tabs). All the tabs have some mandatory fields. what issue am facing is how to validate all the mandatory fields on final tab.

Suppose I have tabs like :

Tab 1    Tab2  Tab3   Tab4

where user can fill any tab and whenever he will click submit button which is on Tab4 i want to validate all the tabs.

I want to execute all the HTMLs in a single click.

PS : I am using html5 and angularjs + jquery

Comment: Can you show some snippet?

Comment: I guess he is talking about form wizard. . at the submit button in a 4th tab he want to execute the validation .

Comment: Yes you are correct@Punit

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend to do that. For example consider if you have name and email in tab1 and when user submit the form in tab4 then if you show 'username is required' and 'email is required' user have no idea of what happened. If you are using angular inline validation with $watch then you are going to end up with lot based on number of fields you have.Did you think about how to switch between tabs?
**Solution:**
Wrap all four tabs code inside a form element. Then you can validate when user submits the form and don't forget to give name attribute.It is mandatory.
**Better way** in my opinion if it is user registration why don't you create wizard with multi steps.